# Basic InnerHTML issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, innerhtml, appendchild

this is the piece of code that I am using in a loop to append an HTML element to a Google Chrome Extension's popup(.html):

- '**wordlist**' is an array of words.
- '**rand**' is the Random number generating function.

Code:

```
for (l=1; l<11; l++) { 
    var i = rand(wordlist.length;
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1");  
    h1.innerHTML = wordlist[i];
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

There are no pre-existing HTML elements. So, this code is appending 10 random words to a blank page.

Now, instead of the words being appended to the page, I want to append links to the page (eg: `http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/**wordlist[i]**`, which is basically a dictionary.com query for that particular word). Also, I want this link to be opened in a [new Chrome tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) when clicked. How do I do this?

**P.S**: I started learning HTML and JS a day before, and I was too excited to start writing some code. I apologize if I have overlooked a simple *Google* solution to my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its as easy as changing

```
 h1.innerHTML = wordlist[i];
```

to exatly what you are after, namely:

```
 h1.innerHTML = "<a href='http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/"+wordlist[i]+"' target='_blank'>"+wordlist[i]+"</a>";
```

To make it open in a new tab you have to add the attribute "target" and give it a value of blank. I think its deprecated in HTML 5 though...

Answer (score 2):

```
for (l=1; l<11; l++) { 
    var i = rand(wordlist.length);
    var a = document.createElement("a");  
    a.setAttribute('href', 'http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/'.wordlist[i]);
    a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    h1.innerHTML = wordlist[i];
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

Basicly just change h1 to a.
Also set the attribute href (the link) and target (where it should be openend).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with the DOM,

```
for (l=1; l<11; l++) { 
    var i = rand(wordlist.length;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + wordlist[i];
    a.appendChild(document.createTextElement(wordlist[i]));
    document.body.appendChild(h1);
}
```

The following will be faster, since you'll append the HTML only once (and DOM operations are costly):

```
var html = "";
for (l=1; l<11; l++) { 
    var i = rand(wordlist.length);
    html += "<a href='http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + wordlist[i] + "'>"
                + wordlist[i]
          + "</a>";
}
document.body.innerHTML += html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
for (l=1; l<11; l++) { 
  var i = rand(wordlist.length);
  var a = document.createElement("a");  
  a.innerHTML = wordlist[i];
  a.href = "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/" + wordlist[i];
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

I fixed a problem in line 2, you'd omitted a closing parenthesis.
I also more obviously changed your h1 to an a, and added a line that sets its href.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, @cynicaloptimist. Any idea on how I can open a new tab by clicking on those links? [link](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create).